# Make STDIN executable with shebang

Tags: shell-script, executable, shebang

I have a program to list database files.

It is called direkly from the shell like

```
db filename
```

to list the whole file, or like

```
db 'filename :: conditions'
```

to list only selected elements ...

---

Another way is to call it with a file, wich contains all parameters.

```
db < parameterfile
```

The content is like (quite the same as the content in '' above):

```
filename
::
conditions
```

---

Now I woud like do make such a file executable. So that i can call just `./parameterfile`.

To use a shebang `#!/usr/bin/env db` failed, because `#` is not a comment sign, I think. I got the error message

```
db - Line 1 near ""#.//r" - " - syntax error

shell returned 26
```

Is there a one-liner to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a shell script that removes the shebang line, if any, and passes the result to `db`. Place this script in a directory of your `PATH`. Otherwise you might have to specify the full path of the script in the shebang line. Use this script as the interpreter for your `parameterfile`.

Example script `runparam` to remove the first line if it is a shebang line:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'FNR>1 || ! /^#!/' "$@" | db
```

Example `parameterfile`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runparam
filename
::
conditions
```

You can run it as

```
./parameterfile
```

In this case the script can assume that there will always be a shebang line.

You could also call the script directly with a parameterfile in the same way as you would call `db`, but this has no advantage.

```
runparam parameterfile
runparam parameterfile1 parameterfile2 [...]
runparam < parameterfile
```

If you will never call `runparam` with a file that doesn't contain a shebang line, you can use `tail` instead of `awk` to unconditionally remove the first line. This might be faster.

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -n+2 | db
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks :) So I can use each: `./parameterfile`, `runparam < parameterfile` or even `runparam parameterfile`.

Comment: @AndyA. Please don't write additional requirements in comments. As this question already has an accepted answer, the best way is to ask a new question with a reference to this one. Show the existing script and ask how to improve it. Show some example input and the resulting data that should get passed to `db`. Alternatively, edit your question, make clear that you edited it after accepting an answer and **append** the additional requirement in the same way. A shebang is also a comment, so your `sed` script would remove it without using `awk`. Try to *understand* the `awk` script .

Comment: @AndyA. Yes, you can delete the comment. Comments are intended for suggestions to improve the question/answer or to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Use awk as a shebang wrapper:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk BEGIN{getline;cmd="db"}{print|cmd}END{exit(close(cmd))}

... "db" commands here ...
```

If your script is *not* supposed to be run directly via `execve(2)` but only via the shell (or via commands like `find -exec`) you have a lot more options, including making it executable *without* prepending it a shebang, and keep it as a valid command script for whatever language that `db` command understands. It all depends on what that language is. For instance, if comment lines in that language start with `//` (as in C++), you can use:

```
// 2>/dev/null; exec db "$0" "$@"

... "db" commands here ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make it a shell script. Either something like:

```
exec db << 'EOF'
filename
::
conditions
EOF
```

(depending on the shell, that either puts the contents of that here document into a tempfile which is made the stdin of the process that will run `db` and deleted before `db` is executed, or a pipe with a shell process feeding the data through it).

Or:

```
tail -n+2 < "$0" | db
filename
::
conditions
```

Here with a pipe (or possibly socketpair with ksh93)  between `tail` and `db`.

Or:

```
exec < "$0"; IFS= read -r ignore; exec db
filename
::
conditions
```

Here with `db`'s stdin being directly opened on the script, with the first line skipped with `read`. That would be the most efficient.